# Trouble saving valid but not invalid palindromes to file using boolean

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am having trouble with the spara-funktion in my code. This is a palindrome check-program and  you are only supposed to be able to save valid palindromes. How do I solve this? This is the message I get when I try to save a valid palindrome:

line 89, in spara
    myFile.write(sparatord + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'

`#-coding: UTF-8-*-`

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox 


main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
top_frame = Tkinter.Frame(main_window, width=100)
middle_frame = Tkinter.Frame(main_window)
bottom_frame = Tkinter.Frame(main_window)
infoLabel = Tkinter.Label(top_frame, height = 7, width=100, text='Skriv in den text du vill kontrollera', font=('courier', 14), bg='purple', fg='black')
inputEntry = Tkinter.Entry(middle_frame, width = 100, bg='white', font=('arial', 14))


def main():
    setupGUI()
    Tkinter.mainloop()

def setupGUI():
    main_window.geometry('500x400') 
    main_window.title('Palindromkollen') 

    Evaluera = Tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text = 'Evaluera texten', command = testaPalindrom).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Instruera = Tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text = 'Instruktioner', command = visaInstruktion).grid(row=2, column=0)
    Spara = Tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text = 'Spara palindrom', command= spara).grid(row=3, column=0)
    Avsluta = Tkinter.Button(bottom_frame, text = 'Avsluta', command = avslutaProgram).grid(row=4, column=0)


    infoLabel.pack()
    top_frame.pack()
    middle_frame.pack()
    bottom_frame.pack()
    inputEntry.pack()


def visaInstruktion():
    infoLabel.configure(bg='purple', fg='white', text= 'I detta program kan du skriva in ord eller \n' 
    'fraser för att kolla om de är palindrom. \n\n'' Skriv in ditt önskade ord och välj "Evaluera texten"\n'
    'Du kan spara dina palindrom genom att klicka på \n' '"Spara palindrom"', font=('courier', 14))


def importText():
    ordnadText = str(inputEntry.get().encode('UTF-8'))
    rensa = (',','!','.',' ','?',':')
    for i in rensa:
        ordnadText = ordnadText.replace(i, "").lower()
    return ordnadText


def testaPalindrom():
    userInput = importText()   

    for i in range (0, len(userInput)-1):
        if userInput[i] != userInput[len(userInput)-1-i]:
            infoLabel.configure(bg='red', text = 'Näpp, det är inte ett palindrom')
            palindrom = False
        else:
            infoLabel.configure(bg='green', text = 'Japp, det är ett palindrom')
            palindrom = True
    return palindrom


def spara():
    sparatord = testaPalindrom()
    try:
        if sparatord == True:
            myFile = open('palindrom.txt', 'a')
            myFile.write(sparatord + '\n')
            myFile.close()
        else:
            infoLabel.config(text='Det är inte ett palidrom, går ej att spara')
    except IOError:
        print 'Ett fel uppstod, kunde inte skriva till fil' 


def avslutaProgram():
    if tkMessageBox.askyesno('Avsluta', 'Vill du stänga palindromkontrollen?'):
        main_window.destroy()    

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myFile.write(sparatord + '\n')
```

to:

```
myFile.write(str(sparatord) + '\n')
```

or use:

```
myFile.write('%s\n'%sparatord)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function testaPalindrom() return True/False value and not palindrom which provide user. Next you try to write that boolean value to file concatenated with \n which is unsupported operation.

You must change your function to return True/False and palindrom value and if True is returned save to file that second value returned.

To joining string better use format function eg: '{}\n'.format(sparatord).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write out the boolean result of the `testaPalindrom()` function. You probably wanted to write out the user input instead:

```
def spara():
    is_palindrome = testaPalindrom()
    try:
        if is_palindrome:
            myFile = open('palindrom.txt', 'a')
            myFile.write(importText() + '\n')
            myFile.close()
        else:
            infoLabel.config(text='Det är inte ett palidrom, går ej att spara')
    except IOError:
        print 'Ett fel uppstod, kunde inte skriva till fil'
```

Here we save the result of `importText()` instead of the boolean result of the boolean return value of `testaPalindrom()`.

Note that you don't need to explicitly test for `is_palindrome == True`; `if` already *does* that test for you.